# Big O notation for triangular numbers?

Tags: big-o

What's the correct big O notation for an algorithm that runs in [triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) time? Here's an example:

```
func(x):
  for i in 0..x
    for j in 0..i
      do_something(i, j)
```

My first instinct is `O(n²)`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: You are right... O((n+1) choose 2) = O(n^2) by definition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, N*(N+1)/2, when you drop the constants and lower-order terms, leaves you with N-squared.

Answer (score 2):

The computation time increases by the factor of N*(N + 1)/2 for this code. This is essentially O(N^2).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `O(n^2)` is definitly correct. If I recall correctly, O is anyway always an upper bound, so `O(n^3)` should IMO also be correct, as would `O(n^n)` or whatever. However `O(n^2)` seems to be the most tight one that is easily deductable.

Answer (score 0):

when the input increases from N to 2N
then running time of your algorithm will increase from t to 4t

thus running time is proportional to the square of the input size

so algorithm is O( n^2 )

Answer (score -1):

If you think about it mathematically, the area of the triangle you are computing is `((n+1)^2)/2`. This is therefore the computational time: O(((n+1)^2)/2)

Comment: You started so well: area of a triangle ≈ area of a square so `O(n²)`

Answer (score -4):

O(!n) handles cases for a factorial computation (triangular time). 

 It can also be represented as O(n^2) to me this seems to be a bit misleading as the amount being executed is always going to be half as much as O(n^2) would perform.

Comment: By definition, `O(0.5 * n^2) == O(n^2)` (an equality that holds for any non-zero constant factor, in fact), so from a strictly theoretical perspective this is not misleading. :-)

Comment: -1.  A [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is not the same as a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Factorial is `product({1…n})`, triangle number is `sum({1…n}) ≈ n²`.