# How to calculate big O notation for this nested loop?

Tags: big-o

if I have for example this simple code

```
for (i =1;i<=n;i++)
for (j=1 ;j<=i;j++)
   count++;
```

for  this line

```
for (i =1;i<=n;i++)
```

if I say that the time for 'i' to get a value  is T   then i will increase n+1 times since the condition is i<=n so the time for increasing i is   (n+1)*T the condition will be asked n+1 times so lets say that the time needed to check the condition is T aswell then  the total time for it to complete is (n+1)*T and i++ will be executed n times because when the condition is asked if i(in this case i is n+1)  <=n it will be false so it wont increase i so the total time for executing this single loop would be  (n+1)*T+(n+1)*T+n*T or  (n+1+n+1+n)*T = (3n+2)*T  so big O for this case would be n 
but I dont know how to calculate for the second loop I was thinking if it would be  n*[(3n+2)*T]  and big O for this would be n^2 but I am not too sure if you dont understand what I am saying or if I made a mistake with first loop too if you can please explain in details how to I calculate it for that code .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O notation for triangular numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179338/big-o-notation-for-triangular-numbers)

Comment: If we had a penny for every time this *exact* piece of code has been posted without researching first ...

Comment: if I had a penny for everytime people commented something not related to the question   I would ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop will execute `n` times, second loop `i` times, for each `i` from the outer loop. At the beginning, `i=1`, so the inner loop will have only one iteration, then `i=2, i=3..` until `i` reaches the value `n`. Therefore, the total number of iterations is `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2`, which gives `O(n^2)`.