# Runtime complexity of a nested for loop but the inner one only goes up to the outer one's current index

Tags: loops, time-complexity

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(i):
      print j
```

Despite the inner loop going only up to the length of the outer loop's current index, can I still claim this is O(n^2) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O notation for triangular numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179338/big-o-notation-for-triangular-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

A loop counting to `n` describes a line, a nested loop both counting to `n` describes a square.

When the inner loop goes up to the outer loop's index, you cover half the square in a triangle shape:

```
+----+
|.   |
|..  |
|... |
|....|
+----+
```

so you could predict the runtime more accurately by calculating the area of a triangle. But Big-O notation is not about getting an exact runtime, but about making a comparison for how the runtime will scale as you add more data. You want to know which [of these lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#/media/File:Comparison_computational_complexity.svg) your program will be closest to. The size of the triangle still increases proportional to `n*n`. Covering half the square is not enough change to shift the program closer to a different complexity class.